# VBA How to remove blank rows

Tags: excel, vba

In VBA in excel, I want to know how I can automatically remove rows in my spreadsheet table where all the columns in the row are blank. For example If I have a table with four columns from A-D, if a row has all columns blank, then how can I remove it from the table automatically? Is this possible?

Can somebody provide a sample code for this please?

Thanks

Comment: You need to try and fix the problem yourself and post some stuff you've tried. Have you tried anything? It's a common problem so lots of information on this site and Google about it.

Comment: @Sam I don't do VBA coding, never done it, I am just doing a favour for a cousin as he wanted help on a spreadsheet but didn't expect to do any coding. Honestly I have checked on Google but a lot of info is just dealing with using show/hide columns, I want to know how not to simply include blank rows as it inserts a whole table into a nother table but this means including the blank rows which I have not filled in

Comment: the solution posted below should work in your situation...

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
Sub RowKiller()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, r As Range
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    For i = N To 1 Step -1
        Set r = Range("A" & i & ":D" & i)
        If wf.CountA(r) = 0 Then
            r.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Does this require a button to be clicked for this to be achieved or will this be done automatically at any time. In other words is RowKiller() assigned to anything?

Comment: When I tested the macro, I ran it directly from the menu system.To use the macro from Excel:

   **1**. ALT-F8
   **2**. Select the macro
   **3**. Touch RUN

Comment: Im using Mac excel 2011 so guessing it is different commands to run the Macros?

Comment: not sure.......is there a **Developer** Tab on your version of Excel??

Comment: There is a developer tab, it contains the following options "Editor", "Macros", "Record", "Relative Reference" and some others. If I click on "Macros" then it asks me to assign Macros which is known as "Sheet32.RowKiller". As what I did was open up the editor for this worksheet and copied your code to test, but when I close the editor, nothing happens, still displays the blank rows

Comment: Sorry......I can't help you...on my Developer tab, there is a button called **Visual Basic**.  If pressed it opens the VBE window.....do you have this button??

Comment: I don't have a Visual Basic button but if I press "fn + alt + f11", it will take me to a list of worksheets menu. I double click on a worksheet (in this case sheet32 and then the editor for that worksheet appears. I will provide a link to show a screenshot of my editor which contains your code so you can see what it looks like.

Comment: Here is a link of the screenshot showing the editor and the spreadsheet table where you can see filled in data and blank rows: http://www.dropviewer.com/v.php?i=527a411bb8242.png

Comment: Where is the run button??  Is it one of the buttons above **(General)** /

Comment: IF I click on the General drop down then the only other option is "Worksheet". If I select it then it automatically displays this: 
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)  End Sub. In the other drop down list you can't see in screenshot, it says "RowKiller", click on that and other option is (Declarations)